# Calling API Keys in background and content scripts in WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an API key and secret required for my extension and I've stored them in a file on their own formatted like so.

key.js

```
var APP_KEY = 'App Key Goes Here';
var APP_SEC = 'App Secret Goes Here';
```

manifest.json

```
// manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Trakt for IMDb",
    "version": "0.1a",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
                "js/key.js",
                "js/background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "js/key.js",
                "js/main.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

On the popup pages I can just reference this file like `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/key.js"></script>` and it calls the 2 variables, but I can't work out how to reference it so my background and content scripts can also access them.

I've tried referencing the `key.js` file in my `manifest.json` file as follows

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/key.js",
        "js/background.js"
    ]
}
```

But that doesn't work. I'm getting an `APP_KEY is not defined`

main.js

```
console.log('Content: ' + APP_KEY);
```

Is there any way to try do what I'm doing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a **complete** [mcve]. All the scripts defined in the `background` key [run in the same context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Specifying_background_scripts). Thus, `APP_KEY` and `APP_SEC`, as defined in *key.js*, are available to your code in *background.js*. [continued...]

Comment: [continued]: If you are talking only about getting the information from there to a content script, then you will have to [pass it as a message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts), or in how the content script is started. The specifics depend on your code. Thus, we need a [mcve].

Comment: @makyen thanks I've tried to add some more info. Any ideas?  I see you've mentioned something about how the content script is started?

Comment: All the scripts which are in a single object in the `content_scripts` entry (i.e. one entry in the array defined for `content_scripts`) are loaded into the same context in the order listed within the `js` array. Because you have said that you are having problems, I have actually tested this with the same `key.js` file being included in both `content_scripts` and in `background`.  The variables defined in `key.js` were available to both the content script and the background script. I am unable to test directly with your *manifest.json* because it references files not included in the question.

Comment: In other words, I've tried what you say you are wanting to do and it works as you describe you want it to. This means there is something else going on. What does the browser console (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on Mac) say when you load the extension? Try simplifying your *manifest.json* down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem and [edit] your question with the minimal version (along with adding anything else that is needed to be able to duplicate the issue).

Comment: Using the *manifest.json*, as recently edited in the question: I added a line `"matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],` in the `content_scripts` array[0] object as `matches` is required (add-on won't load without it). I added a *js/background.js* file with contents `console.log('Background: ' + APP_KEY);`  In the Browser console I get both `Background: App Key Goes Here` and (once I navigate to `mozilla.org`) `Content: App Key Goes Here`. I have tried this on both FF48, and Developer Edition. I am unable to duplicate the problem you are having. Did you check the Browser console (Ctrl-Shift-J)?

Comment: BTW: If you make a change to the question which you wish me to look at, please leave a comment with an `@Makyen` in it.  If you do not do so, I am not notified of any change and only see the change if I happen to re-open the page.

Comment: @makyen sorry hadn't notified you yet as I haven't checked yet. Just waiting until I can get to a computer to check it :-)

Comment: No problem about the notification. I just happened to see the change. As to an earlier question: Yes, there is at least one other method than the *manifest.json* `content_scripts` key of starting a content script. One example would be [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript).

Comment: @Mayken thanks for all your help. I've finally been able to test the script. I reloaded the add-on and it is now working! :D

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it is working for you now. I wonder what was going on before to prevent this from working earlier. On the other hand, I have experienced, a couple of times, intermittent issues when loading a known working add-on temporarily (`about:debugging`). But, nothing specific to this issue. Clicking on "Reload" under `about:debugging` resolved those issues. Good luck with your add-on.

Comment: @mayken thanks. Do you want to post your first answer (3rd message) as an answer and I'll mark it? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works the way you desire. A single JavaScript file can be used in both background scripts and content scripts to share identical functions or variables.

All the scripts defined in the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) key [run in the same context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Specifying_background_scripts). Thus, your variables `APP_KEY` and `APP_SEC`, as defined in `key.js`, are available to your code in `background.js`.

All the scripts defined in a single [`js`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#js) key within a [*manifest.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) file's [`content_scripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) key share a single context. This is what allows you to use things like jQuery with your code. I have not checked to see if there is a separate context created for separate `js` lists, if the `matches` key results in both sets being loaded on a particular page, or tab. In addition, I have not checked to see if a single context is shared between the *manifest.json* file's `content_scripts` method of loading content scripts and other methods of loading content scripts (e.g. [`tabs.executeScript‌​()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript)).

The following is a complete extension that has been tested in both Firefox and Google Chrome. In both browsers, the variables defined in `key.js` are available in both the background and content scripts.

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Variables in other files",
    "description": "Test availability of variables from anther JavaScript file",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
                "js/key.js",
                "js/background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
            "js": [
                "js/key.js",
                "js/contentScript.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

*js/key.js*:

```js
var APP_KEY = 'App Key Goes Here';
var APP_SEC = 'App Secret Goes Here';
```

*js/background.js*:

```js
console.log('Background: ' + APP_KEY);
console.log('Background: ' + APP_SEC);
```

*js/contentScript.js*:

```js
console.log('Content: ' + APP_KEY);
console.log('Content: ' + APP_SEC);
```

Console output upon loading extension:

```
Background: App Key Goes Here
Background: App Secret Goes Here
```

Console output upon navigating to [`mozilla.org`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/):

```
Content: App Key Goes Here
Content: App Secret Goes Here
```

I am not sure why this did not work for you when you initially tried it. You have stated in a comment that it is working for you now.

Comment: Thanks again Makyen :-D