# chrome extension: Share constant variables between content.js and popup.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using several constants that are shared between my content.js and popup.js. How can I put them in one file and share them between both?

This does not work, global.js contains the constants

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["global.js", "background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js":      ["global.js", "content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

global.js

```
var TEST = "test"
```

content.js/popup.js:

```
console.log(TEST)
```

in popup.js it prints `TEST is not defined`

Comment: What you are wanting to do works fine in Chrome (I just re-tested it). If it is not working for you, then you are doing something else wrong and we will need a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. NOTE: You have shown how you are including the *globals.js* in your background script, but you have not shown how it is included in your popup.

Comment: While not tagged as [tag:google-chrome-extension], the question [Calling API Keys in background and content scripts in WebExtension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941405/calling-api-keys-in-background-and-content-scripts-in-webextension) is effectively identical and this question could be answered with an identical answer, but there is not enough code in the question to know what the actual problem is.

Comment: I have the same code as in the question you linked, maybe the problem is the run_at? I will try this again tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: I just tried changing that test extension to have `"run_at": "document_end"`. Worked fine (Chrome ver.  54.0.2840.99).  Please provide a **complete** [mcve].

Comment: Is your problem in your background script, or in your popup?  You have only provided the content/background information in your *manifest.json*. You have not provided any information as to the scripts in your popup (need *at least* the popup's HTML, but some of the JavaScript would help).

Comment: I have updated with an MCV. It is still unclear why it doesn't work

Comment: The code you have provided is not sufficient for a [mcve]. A [mcve] means enough code for us to duplicate the problem (i.e. *all* of the minimum amount of code needed to do so). In this case, it specifically means your popup's HTML and popup's JavaScript. If you do update the question with that information, please ping me by leaving a comment with `@Makyen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>` to the HTML file. I thought it was included by default when you specify it in the manifest.json

Comment: This was one of the more likely possible problems. However, without a [mcve] we have to be psychic to be able to *know* that this was your problem. Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40892005/edit) to include *at least* the HTML file so that this being the solution is actually able to be determined from the information contained in the question.

Comment: Note: You *could* have obtained the constants from the background page. Both the popup and the background page are in the same context. You can obtain a reference to the background page's `window` by using [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

Comment: What you specified in the manifest are Content Scripts (that never get injected into extension pages) and Background Scripts (that are in a different document context than the popup)

Comment: Adding a script tag didn't make any difference for me. 
My mistake was declaring the global variable as "const" instead of "var".